# Arduino Zero and micro SD card not working

Tags: sd, arduino-zero

I have an Arduino Zero processor (atsamd21g18a) with a microSD shield connected (check images of schematics)[image: micro]

[image: sd]

The point is that I cant make it to work, not with `sd.h` sketch and not with `sdfat.h` sketch.

Chip-select for the SD card is A3 or digital pin 17.

### sd.h sketch

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  
 while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  SerialUSB.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(A3)) {
    SerialUSB.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  SerialUSB.println("initialization done.");

  if (SD.exists("example.txt")) {
    SerialUSB.println("example.txt exists.");
  } else {
    SerialUSB.println("example.txt doesn't exist.");
  }

  // open a new file and immediately close it:
  SerialUSB.println("Creating example.txt...");
  myFile = SD.open("example.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  myFile.close();

  // Check to see if the file exists:
  if (SD.exists("example.txt")) {
    SerialUSB.println("example.txt exists.");
  } else {
    SerialUSB.println("example.txt doesn't exist.");
  }

  // delete the file:
  SerialUSB.println("Removing example.txt...");
  //SD.remove("example.txt");

  if (SD.exists("example.txt")) {
    SerialUSB.println("example.txt exists.");
  } else {
    SerialUSB.println("example.txt doesn't exist.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup finishes.
}
```

### sdfat.h code

```cpp
const int chipSelect = A3;
/*
 SD card read/write
  
 This example shows how to read and write data to and from an SD card file   
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4
 
 created   Nov 2010
 by David A. Mellis
 updated 2 Dec 2010
 by Tom Igoe
 modified by Bill Greiman 11 Apr 2011
 This example code is in the public domain.
   
 */
#include <SdFat.h>
SdFat sd;
SdFile myFile;

pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);

void setup() {
  delay(5000);
  SerialUSB.begin(9600);
  SerialUSB.println("Serial start");
  //while (!SerialUSB) {}  // wait for Leonardo
  //SerialUSB.println("Type any character to start");
  //while (SerialUSB.read() <= 0) {}
  delay(1000);  // catch Due reset problem
  
  // Initialize SdFat or print a detailed error message and halt
  // Use half speed like the native library.
  // change to SPI_FULL_SPEED for more performance.
  if (!sd.begin(chipSelect, SPI_HALF_SPEED)) sd.initErrorHalt();

  // open the file for write at end like the Native SD library
  if (!myFile.open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_AT_END)) {
    sd.errorHalt("opening test.txt for write failed");
  }
  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  SerialUSB.print("Writing to test.txt...");
  myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");

  // close the file:
  myFile.close();
  SerialUSB.println("done.");

  // re-open the file for reading:
  if (!myFile.open("test.txt", O_READ)) {
    sd.errorHalt("opening test.txt for read failed");
  }
  SerialUSB.println("test.txt:");

  // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
  int data;
  while ((data = myFile.read()) >= 0) SerialUSB.write(data);
  // close the file:
  myFile.close();
}

void loop() {
  // nothing happens after setup
  SerialUSB.println("loop done.");
}
```

I am not sure if it is a hardware or software issue, but soldering and tracks are good.

Its like the hardware gets frozen, so I cant really see the serial messages. I know its not a serial issue because I can make a simple print serial script and it shows up. I think it might be related with libraries, or maybe some hardware limitation?

Can I use any pin as Chipselect? is digitalpin17 / A3 right?

Comment: what do you mean? PA04 is analogpin3 or digitalpin17 on samd21g18a . If you mean the comments on the sketches I use it is because they are examples of arduino and should work on any board as long as you change cs pin, thats why the second says pin4 as cs

Comment: Oop, yep, mis-remembered--pinout confirms.

Comment: Z1 to Z5 are varistors for overvoltage protection? Why does VDD of the SD card connect to 3.3V via a 1.69kOhm resistor and not directly? Can you check with a logic analyzer whether there is correct activity on the SD card's SPI bus? Also in the sdfat.h example you probably want to replace `sd.initErrorHalt();` with `{ sd.initErrorPrint(); SerialUSB.flush(); }` to get the error message.

Comment: Yes, z1 to z5 are varistors of 3,3V. I could not make the sd card to work so I ended up checking schematics on google and I copied what I thought could help. thats why I added the varistors and the series resistor on the vdd. I made a previous question about a proper schematic for sd card because everything I see online is actually different, but didnt really get a proper answer. I dont have a logic analyzer, but I have a scope, I will try to see what I get. I will try the change on the sdfat code. I put a tft screen on the spi, and it does work but it has a different CS.

Comment: Update here. I managed to get the sd card working. Adding a resitor to the 3,3V pin of the sd card was an absolute mistake beacuse it was making the volttage to drop. So I put a jumper there for now. Another thing was adding a pull up resistor on miso. Also one varistor seemed to be damaged so I removed it. Now the SD card is working fine, but the timestamps funcions of sdfat library make the board freeze. I will try to fix that but apparently it involves edditing the library. Does anyone know how to edit the library for this?